# Associating symbol pages with symbols (Workbench)

Tags: documentation, workbench, document-creation

Normally when you have symbol Abc, WorkBench creates a symbol page named *Abc*.
Then when you make a build, type Abc and then press the F1 key, you are sent to the Abc symbol page.

Suppose however that you want to type a string , say *xyz*, but on pressing F1 you want to go to symbol page Abc or, at least, be given Abc page among the search results. Is this possible?

I think it might be. For example, type the exclamation mark (!) and then F1. You are given the choice between the *Factorial*, *Not* and *Run* pages. How were these associations made?

In other words: is it possible to intercept the F1 action? Or somehow indicate for a symbol page which search strings are appropriate? Or use some other hack to obtain this effect?

Comment: This should happen automatically if xyz is a string that appears somewhere on the Abc documentation page...that's the function of the documentation index. If you want to add extra search terms to a page, you can put them under the "Keywords" meta-information heading at the top of the source file for the page.